# Powershell script for specifically OU

Tags: active-directory, security, powershell

Need help with hte following, a script that can export all members of a specifically OU with in that multiple security groups. Location of the OU is; OU=Security Groups,OU=Public folders,OU=Exchange,DC=REGROEP,DC=LOCAL, I hope you will help me with this.

I triend the following;

Script;

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
cd AD:
$MemberList = New-Item -Type file -Force “c:\scripts\GroupMembers.csv”
Import-Csv “C:\Scripts\Groups.csv” | ForEach-Object {
$GName = $_.GroupName
$group = Get-ADGroup $GName
$group.Name | Out-File $MemberList -Encoding ASCII -Append
foreach ($member in Get-ADGroupMember $group)
{
$member.Name | Out-File $MemberList -Encoding ASCII -Append
  }
$nl = [Environment]::NewLine | Out-File $MemberList -Encoding ASCII -Append
}
```

CSV;

```
GroupName
OU=Security Groups,OU=Public folders,OU=Exchange,DC=REGROEP,DC=LOCAL
```

Error I get;

```
Get-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a    non-null argument and try the command again.
At C:\scripts\PF users.PS1:6 char:21
+ $group = Get-ADGroup <<<<  $GName
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup

Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument
 that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\scripts\PF users.PS1:8 char:38
+ foreach ($member in Get-ADGroupMember <<<<  $group)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADGroupMember],     ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :     ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Comment: This is not a "write my script for me" service, and nor is this an especially complex bit of powershell. How about you tell us what you've tried already and what errors you're getting.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want.
Do you want to export members of an OU to csv, and then if the object is a group, do you want its members ?

Comment: I have an OU with security groups in it, each group in that OU has members. I want a CSV with like;

Sec.Group1   -Member1
             -Member2
Sec.Group2   -Member1
             -Member2

Answer (score 2):

```
$outfile = 'Groups.csv'
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=customOU,DC=panic,DC=org"

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group |
        Select name, objectClass, @{Expression={$group.Name}; Label='Group'} |
            Export-CSV -Path $outfile -NoTypeInformation `
                                      -Encoding ASCII `
                                      -Append `
                                      -Verbose
}
```

Should work in PowerShell v2 too. Tested: v4+

Groups.csv:

```
"name","objectClass","Group"
"User1","user","Group1"
"User2","user","Group1"
"User3","user","Group2"
"User4","user","Group2"
"User5","user","Group3"
"User6","user","Group3"
```

If you've got gajillions of these, you'd probably want to store the results in a PSCustomObject and then dump it into a CSV, avoiding touching the disk for every line of output.